# PdfSharpCore font size units is not making sense and doesn't seem right

Tags: .net, pdf, .net-core, pdfsharp, pdfsharpcore

I'm confused by the font sizes in [PdfSharpCore](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore). The documentation for `XFont` says that the font size is specified as "emSize".

According to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html), em size represents the font size. According to [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp), *The size of an EM or percent depends on its parent.*
And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)), it originally meant the width of the letter 'M'.

How is it possible to specify the font size using the size of a font, a value that depends on its "parent" or based on any other attribute of an existing font when there is no existing font?

In practice, the value I specify appears to be interpreted as very close to points. But if it is really specifying points, why would it be documented as "emSize?"

Can anyone clarify how I can use an em size to set the font size? What em size would I use to specify 14 point?

Comment: @KJ: The point is, if "one em in a 16-point typeface is 16 points," then how do I specify the original typeface using em units? The size of the typeface has not yet been defined. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @KJ: I just want to set the font size. Let's say, for example, I want a 12 point font, so how many ems is that? I don't think it makes any sense.

Comment: @KJ: You've said a lot of strange stuff. But I can't see where you've made any attempt to answer what I asked.

Comment: You probably should edit your question and point out where exactly *the PdfSharpCore documentation says the font sizes are specified in "emSize"*; quoting the exact wording and the context in which it is said may help, too. Based on that quote answers here may specifically respond to it. It's not impossible that the documentation in parts is simply misleading, but it also is not impossible that the context in which that is said makes the mentioning of emSize sensible.

Comment: @mkl: You can see the `XFont` constructors [here](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/master/PdfSharpCore/Drawing/XFont.cs). The parameter is called `emSize`, and the parameter description says *"The em size."*

Comment: *"You can see the `XFont` constructors [here](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/master/PdfSharpCore/Drawing/XFont.cs). The parameter is called `emSize`"* - Reading more of that file one sees that the `emSize` is in particular used in ratioes with the `UnitsPerEm` value read from the tables of the font file. Apparently PdfSharpCore attempts to base a number of sized on that value from the font. I'm not into font specifics, so I cannot say whether that makes sense. The PDF spec does not reference this value anywhere. To me it feels like a fudge factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XFont` class has an `emSize` parameter because it mimics the `Font` class of GDI+ which already has an `emSize` parameter. That is the simple explanation why the developer of PDFsharp chose that name (I asked him). I did not yet find further information why Microsoft chose that name.

`emSize` is the name of the parameter, but the unit is not `em`. The default unit is `Point`, but other units can be set. The `emSize` parameter defines the `em` of the font to be used.

Forget the W3C documentation in this case: This is not CSS, there is no "parent" and no option to use relative sizes (percent values).

To get a font of size 14 points, just specify 14. The `emSize` parameter specifies the height of the font.

The answer by K J might explain how Microsoft came to the name `emSize`.

From Wikipedia: "An em (from English em quadrat) is a unit in the field of typography, equal to the currently specified point size. For example, one em in a 16-point typeface is 16 points. Therefore, this unit is the same for all typefaces at a given point size."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)

From the Font documentation linked below: "The em-size, in points, of the new font."
From the PDFsharp XML documentation: "Gets the em-size of this font measured in the unit of this font object." The default unit is points. So with PDFsharp the value "14" gives a font height of 14 points.

See also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-drawing-font-ctor(system-string-system-single)

Comment: I've found a number of sources that say an EM is equal to 0.083645886860081 points. It's hard to know what to believe any more. Would've been so much simpler if font sizes were set in points.

Comment: @JonathanWood From the `Font` documentation linked above: "The em-size, in points, of the new font." From the PDFsharp XML documentation: "Gets the em-size of this font measured in the unit of this font object." The default unit is points. So with PDFsharp the value "14" gives a font height of 14 points. And one point is 1/72 inch, but you can find many sources that will give you different definitions for a point - but those do not relate to PDF files or PDFsharp. There are different definitions for "inch", too. Here an inch is 2.54 cm and a point is 1/72 inch.

Comment: @JonathanWood From Wikipedia: "An em (from English em quadrat) is a unit in the field of typography, equal to the currently specified point size. For example, one em in a 16-point typeface is 16 points. Therefore, this unit is the same for all typefaces at a given point size." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)

Comment: Well, I appreciate what you're saying. But I did find half a dozen sites showing that em is different from points. Also, many sites describe em as being based on an existing font. And it still makes no sense why we're using the term em if in fact we are referring to points. That's what I find confusing. But your comments above are helpful. In particular the Microsoft documentation, which I interpret as saying *"nevermind that we call it em size, we really mean points."*

Comment: The `Font` class has constructors where the unit can be specified. The default is Point if no unit is given. Your value "1 pt = 0.083645886860081 em" is correct for an EM size of 12 points, a 12 point font. For other font sizes you will get other values. For a 10-point font, it is "1 pt = 0.1 em". The `emSize` parameter defines what "1 em" will be for the new font. "We call it em-size because it defines the em of the font."

Answer (score 2):

Technically, per PDF specification, the font size in 'Tf' operator is just a scale factor.
The final font size is given by this formula:

```
|Tfs×Th   0    0|
|  0    Tfs    0| × Tm × CTM
|  0    Trise  1|

Tfs   - text font size for Tf operator (usually the font size in the API)
Th    - text horizontal scaling
Trise - text rise
Tm    - text matrix
CTM   - current transformation matrix
```

Assuming the default user unit is the PDF point, the Tm and CTM are identity matrices (no scaling), Trise=0, Th=100 (no scaling), then the final font size is Tfs in PDF points.

Comment: Well, I still have no idea what em size I should specify if I want, for example, a 12 point font.

Comment: @KJ: Where are they saying ems are their values for points? If it's points, it seems like they'd just call it points.

Comment: @KJ: I never think of point size as saying anything other than the height of the font.

Comment: @KJ: A point should always represent 1/72 inches. In general, this means that is the size when printed to the page. Obviously, any other display devices should adjust accordingly. I don't know or care what the actual size the font is on those devices. When you say length/height, I have no idea what you mean by length. Some fonts are more narrower than others. So I expect a 12 point font to be printed at 12/72 inches. In this case, I just don't care about the width.

Comment: @JonathanWood I think you can safely use 12 in order to get a 12 point font. You can create a sample file and we can look inside to see the actual value used with Tf operator.

Comment: @iPDFdev: I will try looking at the file to see if it shows the size in a way that would clarify. But if 12 em really does equal 12 point, then I'm still confused why it didn't just use points.

Comment: @JonathanWood "em" is whatever value you give it. If you create a font that is 12 points high, then "1 em" will be 12 points. Don't get confused if conversion sites tell you "1 EM = 11.95516046919 points (pt)". "1 em" can have many different sizes just like "1 bar of chocolate" can have many different weights.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow: *"'1 em' can have many different sizes just like [...]"* And that is exactly the reason why using em to specify the font size makes zero sense to me.

Comment: @JonathanWood The name of the parameter is "emSize" because it defines the size of "em". It does not use the unspecific unit "em", it defines the unit "em" for the new font. Makes perfect sense to me. It is so simple and clear.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow: What's the difference between the size of "em" and the unit "em"? Those things sound like they should be the same thing to me. I don't find that simple and clear at all.

Comment: @JonathanWood There is no fixed unit "em", even though some conversion sites treat it like that. With a mechanical typewriter, 1 em is about 1 pica, defined by the hardware. With TrueType fonts, 1 em is what you pass to the constructor of the `Font` or `XFont` class. There is no "em" before you construct the font. The "em" of the font is the value you pass to the constructor. Scalable fonts, scalable "em".

Answer (score 2):

To see where emSize originates we need to go back in time to the Printers Manuals when [Modern MECHANICK](https://ia804706.us.archive.org/33/items/mechanickexercis00moxo_0/mechanickexercis00moxo_0.pdf) printing started and the best source is the PDF from 1683 where all letters were described as based on 42 units x 42 units as described on page 98-99 starting with

```
..the divided Line on the
Left Hand of A is divided into forty and two equal
Parts ; and that Length is the Body, thus : J being
an Aʃcending and Deʃcending Letter, viz. a long
Letter, ʃtands upon forty two Parts, and therefore
fills the whole Body.
....
And as there is three Heighths or Sizes to be con-
ʃidered in Letters Cut to the ʃame Body, ʃo is there
three Sizes to be conʃidered, with reʃpect to the
Thickneʃʃes of all theʃe Letters, when the Punches
are to be Forged : For ʃome are m thick ; by m
thick is meant m Quadrat thick, which is juʃt ʃo thick
as the Body is high : Some are n thick ; that is to
say, n Quadrat thick, viz. half ʃo thick as the Body
is high : And ʃome are Space thick ; that is, one
quarter ʃo thick as the Body is high ; though Spaces
are ʃeldom Caʃt ʃo thick, as ʃhall be shewed when
we come to Caʃting : and therefore, for diʃtinction
ʃake, we ʃhall call theʃe Spaces, Thick Spaces.
```

There were exceptions then too

```
... moʃt of the
Swaʃh Letters ; which being too thick to ʃtand on
an m, muʃt be Forged thicker, according to the
Work-man’s Reaʃon.
```

We would call that in modern terms the "Draughtsman's License"

Note they could have called it 1 bodySize or jaySize but it was easier to describe the variable of widths by  the most quadratile of all the ascendant letters. the finished size of any fount was based on a stock width of the M. Thus the overall "Fount Body" size was considered its "m Size", an abstract value based on square width = height.

[image]

Then as now the programming consideration was the precise width of a line of text (using variable height letters) so the page Rule Length/Width would be based on a total number of m's. Today we would use for matrix line printers such as POS roll printing 10cpi or 12cpi.

Thus for a font of approximately 14 points high the exact emSize will be  14 points.

In programming we describe a font just as then

family, emSize, style

Roman, 14, italic

Where the emSize is 14 units (traditionally was pica's wide, but in PDF=points not CPI nor mm nor other CGI pixel unit length)

In Engineering we may say `let emSize = 2 mm` high to get precision of exactly 2 mm high letters

In Wooden Press we may say `let emSize= 2"` wide for block printing

In PDF term we say `let emSize - ## points` for a highly variable range of fonts where none actually use a fixed height or width but are based on the abstract square unit of ##x1/72"